# edit resolution in flash page

Tags: html, css, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

that's my flash site , I want to extend the gray box to reach the edge of the HTML page . I mean that I don't want the background color to appear **all I want in the page the flash site in the resolution of the page whatever the PC resolution** .
sorry for my bad English .
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your embedded SWF to be 100% width and height, you need to do it in the HTML/CSS. First make sure there is no padding or margin around the edges:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Then make sure you set the width and height of the embedded SWF object is set to 100%.

You also might need to set the SWF param "scale" to "noScale".

Comment: how to make You also might need to set the SWF param "scale" to "noScale".
by action script3 ????

Comment: You set noScale in the HTML, not ActionScript. Take a look at this: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/mx2004/fullscreen.htm